# How can I print in colour from mac book air when olivetti printer defaults is set to print mono

Tags: macbook-pro

We have just one Mac user in the office. Everyone else is on HP Pro. Our Olivetti MF2400 is set to print in mono which is fine for HP users as we can choose colour from the file drop down however, there does not seem to be such an option on the mac book air.

Any advice?

Thanks
G

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I am assuming that you are using a relatively newer version of OS X on your Mac and at least Windows 7 for the HP Pros.

This is a driver issue.  The only thing that can override a default value is a user setting on a driver.  I went to the [Olivetti MF 2400 support site](http://www.olivettiuk.com/support/541/d-color-mf2400#filecat_1) and found these drivers:

[image]

If you notice, there are two MacOSX drivers that are "PS Mono;"  that's Post Script Monochrome.  I suspect you are using one of those drivers.  Try downloading and using the "PS" version of the driver (the second one being that it is for 10.6 which is the version of OS X that only supported the Intel CPU and not the PowerPC.

That said, this is a discontinued printer and finding drivers may become much more difficult as time progresses.  You may be able to extend its useful life by sharing this printer (via CUPS in Linux/Unix) and emulating something a bit more generic like an HP Color Jet.  It's not the cleanest solution, but if you just want basic color printing, it will probably get the job done.